# Find trendline for minimum (not mean) values in distribution

Tags: r, regression, quantile-regression, scatterplot, extreme-value

I would like to perform something like a linear regression on my distribution of data, but I'm interested in a trendline that estimates the **minimum**, *not mean*, value for each time bin. I'd like to do this in R.

The image below shows a scatterplot of the minimum value for each time bin. The black line is a typical linear regression, which estimates the mean. What I'd like is something like what I painted in red - an estimation of the minimum.

[image]

My data look like this:

[image]

Those are just the first few lines but you get the idea.

Comment: The *sample* minimum you already know; the *population* minimum only exists for distributions with a restricted range & you haven't said anything about the distributional assumptions: are you asking about predicting the minimum for a newly sampled data-set?

Comment: I am asking about predicting the population minimum based on the samples that I have. I would assume a normal distribution of the population.

Comment: To my eye, it's not clear how you'd mathematically define the minima points along your red line. You know what you want, by eye, but I can't see a clear and precise definition. You could take your standard regression and then subtract some value of the SD from it. Or do a quantile regression with a small quantile number (at some point, it will break, so you can't just use 0 or 0.01).

Comment: That's easy: the population minimum for a normally distributed variable is $-\infty$.

Comment: Perhaps take a step back & explain what you're trying to learn from the data. It's hard to imagine why the trend in the minimum of a lot of time bins with different numbers of observations in each is of any interest.

Comment: Thanks Wayne! I'm trying out quantile regressions now. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Charcha: You could answer your question yourself, and tell us how quantile regression worked out?