# Estimate minimum values of the dependent variable

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, extreme-value

We know that linear regression estimates the expected mean value of a dependent variable, as a function of the independent variables.

I would like to know, however, if there is any theory about some kind of linear regression that estimates the minimum value that the dependent variable can assume, as a function of the independent variables?

EDIT:
The dependent variable has Poisson distribution.

Comment: Interesting question. Perhaps you could look at the lower bound of some confidence interval (e.g., 80%, 90%, 95%, 99%) for predicted values? Why are you interested in this question?

Comment: not sure if you want to model *minima.* Modeling quantiles might be better https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78001/find-trendline-for-minimum-not-mean-values-in-distribution?rq=1 .

Comment: You are looking at Extreme Value Theory.  Without specifics though that is probably all we can say.

Comment: Hi, @MarkWhite, thank you for the tip and the interest ... well, I'm interested in this subject because, in my study, the results of interest are when the dependent variable is as smallest as possible, because it represents a cost. Thus, I want to estimate how small my dependent variable can be (to look for this), as a function of the values of the independent variables.

Comment: Usually, when we seek to optimize anything, cost included, we use a function that is not linear and has a minimum value that is not extreme. For example, one uses multiple linear equations that intersect to find the optimum of several factors. Another example, quadratic equations that have positive square term coefficients. Without seeing the data itself, and the variables themselves, it is not possible to see how to model and/or transform parameters and select fit equations to better model it.

Comment: I'm not saying there isn't as I don't know, but, If the response variable is normally distributed, how can it take a minimum value?

Comment: @PM there's nothing in the question that indicates an assumption of normality.

Comment: @Dani Are you asking about there being a curved surface that you want to find a minimum of (e.g. $E(Y|x) = f(\,\underline{x}\,)$, find the argmin (the value of the minimimizer), $x^*$ of $\hat f$, or are you asking about finding the lower limit of the conditional distribution at each $\,\underline{x}\,$ for a linear relationship?  See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoNFL.png) ... which one is it?

Comment: @Glen_b Absolutely. I did wonder tho' how it would work in that particular case. There's nothing in the question that rules out normality either.

Comment: @Glen_b I'm definitely looking for to do what is illustrated in the first figure of your example. Excuse me if I was not clear enough. To answer the question raised here, the dependent variable has poisson distribution.

Comment: If the variable is Poisson, then the minimum of the distribution is always *0*, no matter what its parameter.

Comment: @Glen_b I understand that for a poisson variable, the minimum value is zero. But I would still like to know if there is not a way to find a curve that shapes the data "underneath" and not "in the middle" ... I am coming to the conclusion that Quantile Regression with very small tau will end up being the solution for me .

Comment: My point was that **for a Poisson response variable**, the actual curve describing the minimum is $y=0$ for all $x$. It *can't* be anything else. If you want the minimum, *that's what it is*, every time. If you think it's anything but that, either your model is wrong or you don't have the minimum of the conditional distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b I get what you're saying. In fact, I can not call it what I want to be minimal. What I want is more to an interpolation of the values, in the lowest possible region of the plotting data. Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you clarify "in the lowest possible region of plotting the data"? The lowest *possible* plotted value for a Poisson is, again, *always $0$, for every $x$*. Do you mean something else? It's hard to be sure what you seek - e.g. it might be possible to work out an expected lowest order statistic at each $x$ (or even an envelope of expected lowest order statistics), which would depend on how much data you have at each $x$ value -- the more data, the closer to $0$ that would go, for a given mean, but as the mean increased the  lowest expected order statistic  would tend to move up away from 0.

Comment: @Glen_b when I say "in the lowest possible region of plotting the data", I mean "in the lowest possible region of plotting sample data".

Comment: Again, the lowest *possible* position for observations is 0. You're going to have to be clearer  (for one thing you may want to choose a different word than *possible* that relates more to what you intend). Are you just after the highest line that's a lower envelope for the observations, rather anything that's really telling you about the population? Can you confirm or deny the previous question about expected lowest order statistics? The currently posted question still has the answer "$y=0$, for all $x$" and your most recent comment on it has the same answer.